# Capitalize everything before a Symbol

Tags: notepad++, regex

I need to find a possibility of capitalize every word BEFORE a symbol.

Example:

```
bla apple banana=Bla apple banana
```

Result:

```
Bla Apple Banana=Bla apple banana
```

I want to Capitalize every first letter of every word before "="

How do I do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modification from @Toto's answer to capitalize all words before the `=` sign.

- Find what: `(\b\w+)(?=.+\=)`
- Replace by: `\u$0`
- Enable Match Case
- Search mode: Regular Expression

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: Cheers! Works good, however just as a note, this will treat 's as a word, e.g. "sam's apple" becomes "Sam'S Apple". I could fix it with a simple 'S='s replacement though, just though I'd mention it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^|\G\h+)(\b[a-z]+)`
- Replace with: `$1\u$2`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(           # group 1
    ^           # beginning of line
  |           # OR
    \G          # restart from last match position
    \h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
)           # end group 1
(           # group 2
    \b          # word boundary
    [a-z]+      # 1 or more letters
)           # end group 2
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
\u          # uppercase 1rst letter
$2          # content of group 2
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: It seems that your answer currently only capitalizes the word before the `=` sign, instead of all words before it.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Appreciate it a ton. However as Reddy pointed out it only capitalizes the first Letter of the last word before =. So the result is "bla apple Banana=Bla apple banana", instead of the desired "Bla Apple Banana=Bla apple banana".

Comment: @Emjay: See my udated answer.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: You're right, answer updated.

Comment: This doesn't work if there are any symbols (hyphens, brackets, apostrophes, dots, etc.). However the other answer worked for me - thank you guys!